# Combine multiple tikz pictures into the same page in standalone environmemt

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

I draw two circles in a standalone environment using the following code, but they are always rendered on separate pages.

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{open}=[circle,draw,minimum size=5mm]
    \node[open] (c1) at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{open}=[circle,draw,minimum size=5mm]
    \node[open] (c1) at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How to combine them (say vertically) and put them into one page?

Comment: Welcome. // Nice question, couldn't resolve it from the manual. However, two remarks: 1) You already load package tikz with the \documentclass statement. 2) As a bypass, you can create a \pic for each drawing and place them like you would place nodes in a single tikzpicture environment. See http://tikz.dev for details on \pic , i.e. https://tikz.dev/tikz-pics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution is to remove the option `tikz` from `\documentclass`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{open}=[circle,draw,minimum size=5mm]
    \node[open] (c1) at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{open}=[circle,draw,minimum size=5mm]
    \node[open] (c1) at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to put them vertically instead?

Comment: @ZhengyuanYue Use `\documentclass[border=2pt,varwidth]{standalone}` to get a vertical layout

Comment: You could put them into a minipage or tabular.